# Unable to add more components to picker view

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I pretty sure I'm using the method correctly:

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsinPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 3;
}
```

Shouldn't that be enough to create three components in the picker, because when I run the program it just shows the one component that I originally had.

Here the code I used:

```
    // Create the picker
-(void) createPickerData {

    //Set up a path to the plist
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WheelData.plist"];
    NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];

    NSArray *letterArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[plistData objectForKey:@"LetterArray"]];
    numberOfLetters = [letterArray count];


    NSMutableArray *firstLetterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfLetters];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++) {
        [firstLetterArray addObject:[[letterArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Letter"]];
    }

    pickerDataForName = [NSArray arrayWithArray:firstLetterArray];


}

// Positions the picker on the screen
-(void) showPicker {

    CGRect rect =CGRectMake(60, 650, self.frame.size.width - 120, 400);

    enterNamePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    enterNamePicker.delegate = self;

    [self addSubview:enterNamePicker];

}

//This sets the number of components wheels (or columns) in a picker view
-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsinPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {

    //Creating 3 wheels
    return 3;
}

// Defines the how many rows (or items) are in the picker view
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [pickerDataForName count];

}

// is run anytime you change the picker
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {



    //Here we are seting up a label for each object in each row / component
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 50)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:universalFont size:30];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [pickerDataForName objectAtIndex:row]];


    return label;
}

-(void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSLog(@"Row %i selected", [enterNamePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]);

}
```

Comment: Could it be about your data source?

Comment: Well I just want three components with the same data in all of them. I have the first component set up completely with the data and all that working just fine. I just assumed that if I added more components, by default, they would all have the same data.

Comment: Could you share that code to check whether there are any problems or not?

Comment: Are you sure this code isn't crashing?  `numberOfComponentsinPickerView` should be `numberOfComponentsInPickerView` (uppercase `I` for `In`).

Comment: Ok, that worked, but for some reason it looks like the picker views are overlapping each other and its hard to see the contents.

Comment: That's probably because in viewForRow, code is setting width of each label to the whole container view width instead of the width of each component.